# Creating Temporary tables in Mysql using java on a read-only server results in error

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, slave

I have a read-only slave for my production database and I am trying to run a procedure that generates a report. The procedure creates a temporary table, inserts some records, and selects the results from the table. This works fine when I run the procedure through the command line interface or a db UI tool (Navicat), the table is created without any issues, I can insert, and receive the correct report.

The problems begin when I try to call that same procedure using the jdbc in Java. When I run the procedure I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.executeQuery(CallableStatement.java:956)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
```

I am using the same user in the java application and from Navicat, and I need to use a temporary table because the results of this report are used in other reports as well. I have looked online but cannot seem to find any reason why this would work normally but not when run through java.

Comment: Obviously you have different access restrictions or you wouldn't be getting this error. Are you sure you're connecting the same way? In MySQL it's the combination of username + IP (or local) that determines access, not just username.

Comment: In all cases I connect the the server via an ssh tunnel and then connect to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I was using a transaction and the START TRANSACTION call was causing the MySQL error when I called the procedure from Java. Adding a check for @@read_only before starting the transaction fixed the issue. (Still don't know why it was working in Navicat and not Java)